# Relation between DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT and GV$SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was trying to create a dashboard comparing historical executions and current executions of multiple SQL statements. I have noticed some differences between stats in GV$SQL and DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT. Could you please help us to understand below point.

For eg: For one SQL_ID i have 37 rows in DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT and DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT (has same PHV and same child number for all). Sum of executions_delta column gives me 91. However, as per GV$SQL, EXECUTIONS is only 40.

Min begin interval time from DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT is 23/May/2018 and max end interval time is 5/June/2018. First_load_time and last_load_time in v$sql is 31 Jan 2018 and 18 June 2018 respectively.

Please help me to understand why DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT could have more number of executions within a shorter period of time comparing to gv$sql values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentaion of [DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4051.htm)  states

> DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT displays historical information about SQL statistics. This view captures the top SQL statements based on a set of criteria and captures the statistics information from V$SQL.
>
> The delta value is the value of the statistics from the BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME to the END_INTERVAL_TIME in the DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT view.

So this is the explanation why the view DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT has more executions. This is historical view preserving all captured execution. Contrary, if a cursor is flushed from shared pool, its statistics disapear from `V$SQL` (or `GV$SQL`).

The second point goes to the time interval related to the statistics. In DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT are the `delta` statistics clearly related to the interval between the two snapshots - defined in the view `DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT`.
In `V$SQL` there is no comparable time interval, espectially you can not compare `first_load` with `begin_interval_time`.

So for your report comparing the historical and current statistics of the cursor you could use only the view DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT interpreting the last snapshot delta statistics as the current and the rest as the historical part.